# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}{(\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x} })}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}{(\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x} })}dx$$.

My attempt: The answer seemed to be $$[\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x} }]_{-1}^{1}$$ but the answer is coming incorrect.
The actual answer should be $2/(1+e)$.Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is a discontinuity at $x=0$.  Thus, you need to break up the integral there.  The correct answer looks like

$$\left [\frac1{1+e^{1/x}} \right ]_{-1}^{0^-}  - \left [\frac1{1+e^{1/x}} \right ]_{1}^{0^+}$$

Note that in the left expression, the $e^{1/x}$ term vanishes as $x \to 0^-$, while on the right, the $e^{1/x}$ term blows up as $x \to 0^+$.  Thus, the integral is

$$1 - \frac1{1+e^{-1}} - 0 + \frac1{1+e} = \frac{2}{1+e}$$

as expected.

Comment: Awesome.That was really tricky!